# С++: Как найти пересечение двух Set или Vector

Tags: c++, массивы, vector, set

Допустим есть два Set или Vector.
Например:

```
vector<int> a {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
vector<int> b {1, 5, 8};
vector<int> Intersect;

set<int> a1 { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
set<int> b1 { 1, 5, 8};
set<int> Intersection;
```

Как мне найти и записать в Intersect или Intersection все элементы из 'b' которые входят в 'a' в другой массив Intersect (в случае vector) или Intersection (в случае Set) ?

Comment: Учить матчасть — https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection

Comment: Я пытаюсь понять алгоритм. Это не применимо.

Comment: Что именно не применимо?

Comment: Готовое решение

Comment: Ну тогда проходите циклами по векторам, сравниваете значение и принимаете решение, заносить в итоговый вектор или нет.

Comment: 1. Вы нигде не написали, что хотите ***понять***, у вас вопрос — как получить результат. 2. Вы не дочитали до конца страницы, там приведена простая, ясная и понятная реализация поиска пересечений. Приходится давать ее в ответе, надеюсь, ответ на собственный вопрос вы прочтете все же...

Answer (score 1):

Если множества отсортированные (как `set`, для `vector` сначала отсортировать), то как вариант

```
template<class InputIt1, class InputIt2, class OutputIt>
OutputIt set_intersection(InputIt1 first1, InputIt1 last1,
                          InputIt2 first2, InputIt2 last2, OutputIt d_first)
{
    while (first1 != last1 && first2 != last2)
    {
        if (*first1 < *first2)
            ++first1;
        else
        {
            if (!(*first2 < *first1))
                *d_first++ = *first1++; // *first1 and *first2 are equivalent.
            ++first2;
        }
    }
    return d_first;
}
```

Или еще более обобщенно

```
template<class InputIt1, class InputIt2, class OutputIt, class Compare>
OutputIt set_intersection(InputIt1 first1, InputIt1 last1,
                          InputIt2 first2, InputIt2 last2, OutputIt d_first, Compare comp)
{
    while (first1 != last1 && first2 != last2)
    {
        if (comp(*first1, *first2))
            ++first1;
        else
        {
            if (!comp(*first2, *first1))
                *d_first++ = *first1++; // *first1 and *first2 are equivalent.
            ++first2;
        }
    }
    return d_first;
}
```